# what could be wrong on my return by the way im using datables.net and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

What could be wrong on my return by the way im using   `datables.net` and laravel. Thanks in advance for your help

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#tbl').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "paginate": true,
  "ajax": "{{ url('admin/allposts') }}",
  "deferRender": true,
  "pagingType": "full_numbers",
  "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 0,
        "data": null,
        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
            //this is the part that i want to display what could be wrong
            return  '<div class="thumbnail" style="width: 250px;">
                        <img src="'data[$i+$a]['creatives_url']'" alt="..." width="100px" height="80px">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                            <p>
                            'data[$i+$a]['program_name']'
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>'
```

Comment: im having problem on the return it wont display that part of a html and json code that's on it it's inside a <td> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
return '<div class="thumbnail" style="width: 250px;">\
    <img src="' + data[$i + $a]['creatives_url'] + '" alt="..." width="100px" height="80px">\
    <div class="caption">\
    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>\
    <p>' + data[$i + $a]['program_name'] + '</p>\
    </div>\
    </div>';
```

I just fixed your return string. Although you're trying to reference `$i` and `$a` in `data[$i + $a]['program_name']`. If these are php variables then echo them using `{{ $i }}`.

Comment: this \ slash is that the one im missing ive tried the + concatenation

Comment: @Lestah so what are you trying to imply? If you don't want to define the html in multiple lines then remove the \ and write them in a single line